# How to create an (FDW) foreign table and map it to a different schema?

Tags: postgresql, postgres-fdw, foreign-data-wrapper

This is how I defined the foreign table:

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE ftbl_employee (
    id UUID,
    name VARCHAR,
)
SERVER company_registry_dbserver
OPTIONS (schema_name 'company', table_name 'company_employee');
```

It created the foreign table successfully. However, when I list the foreign table, It has defaulted to **public** schema. See **foreign_table_schema** column:

```
> select * from information_schema.foreign_tables;
```

| foreign_table_catalog | foreign_table_schema | foreign_table_name | foreign_server_catalog | foreign_server_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sandbox | public | ftbl_employee | sandbox | company_registry_dbserver |

I would like to map it into the **company** schema in our sandbox database server instead of the **public** schema.

Comment: Options' `schema_name` is about the source table. Qualify the foreign table name with a schema prefix, i.e. `CREATE FOREIGN TABLE company.ftbl_employee( ...`

Comment: Tried but It doesn't work unfortunately `schema "company" does not exist`. Btw the `company` does not exist in the current database server. It is on the sandbox database server which is the source of FDW foreign server. :(

Comment: Well, there is no way to create a table in a schema that does not exist and there is no such thing as a foreign schema. Why don't you create `company` schema on the current database server? Just `create schema company;`

Comment: I want to connect the `ftbl_employee` to a different source db which has a `company` schema. what does the `foreign_table_schema` really means? It is a schema on the current db or the schema on the source db?

Comment: It seems to be a schema on the current db. However I would not peek into the guts (information_schema) but rather use the excellent documentation. Have a look [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html).

Comment: And maybe it's easier to use [import foreign schema](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-importforeignschema.html), it seems very clear and unambiguous to me. [alter foreign table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterforeigntable.html) may also be used.

Comment: It seems like its the current db. Now I think I have a different error why the foreign table is still unable to get the data. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

The column `information_schema.foreign_tables` holds the schema where the foreign table is stored locally, **not** the schema of the table in the target database. So, there is no way you can create this foreign table in the schema `company` if it does not exist locally! You need to either **locally** run ..

```
CREATE SCHEMA company;
```

.. or live with the foreign table in the `public` schema. Keep in mind that a foreign table is nothing more than a "gateway" to a table that resides in a different database / server. If you wanna know more details on the foreign table, e.g. `name` or `schema`, check the view `pg_foreign_table`:

```
SELECT relname, ftoptions 
FROM pg_foreign_table 
JOIN pg_class ON ftrelid = oid;
```

Comment: Yes I understand, My situation is there is a local db where I created the foreign table and map that to the source db. The source db *has* a schema named `company`. I think I successfully map the right schema now however it appears that the connection won't allow it.

Comment: @Roel which error message are you getting?

Comment: Connection timed out. Probably this is a configuration error I think Stefanov.sm already answered my question. The `foreign_table_schema` column value is the schema in a local db. Thanks for the answer anyway it will be helpful to others.